# Find SHA256 if I only have part of the string

Tags: sha256

I need to find the SHA256 hash of s string like this: "part1-part2".
I know the SHA256 hash of part1 and I know what part2 represents, but I don't know what is the contents of part1.

Is there any chance I can compute the hash of the whole string using these two?

Comment: What do you mean by saying that you know what part2 represents.  Do you mean you know the contents, or you know the contents will be something in a format that you can predict?

Comment: The contents of part2

Comment: Do you have an idea of the length of part1?

Comment: Yes, I know the length of part1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be able to compute a SHA256 of part1-part2, if you already knew SHA256(part1), and the value for part2.  This relies on a vulnerability in the underlying method of hash construction SHA256 uses (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack).

EDIT: To clarify the algorithm SHA256 will pad any input to a multiple of some given size.

Soo really you could think of it as SHA256(part1||padding), where 'padding' means x00 repeated till size(part1||padding) mod 512 = 0 (since SHA256 has a block size of 512 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Hash_Algorithm).  This becomes a problem if any padding needs to be added to part1.

Comment: Does it work even if I don't have any data from part1 except for its hash and length?

Comment: Yes.  That's why it's an attack.

Comment: I think that "may" is not correct and that this can definitely be done using a length extension attack.

Comment: It can be done, but using padding between part1 and part2, right? So in the end SHA256(part1||part2) will differ from SHA256 (part1||padding||part2).

Comment: Correct.  SHA256part1||part2) != SHA256(part1||padding||part2).